# Does opening files in Office "Protected View" de-anonymize my browsing?

Tags: anonymity, windows

I have read and understand that you should not open files like PDF and Microsoft Office while using Tor because they can access the internet and reveal your real IP address without your knowledge. I occasionally visit links to Microsoft Word documents (.docx) that then contain URLs in them that I would like to open using Tor.

I have noticed that Word opens in "Protected View," whenever it opens a file from the internet. Does "Protected View" prevent the files from accessing the internet? Is there any other reason why opening a file in "Protected View" would be unsafe or not anonymous?

I run Tor on Windows 7 and 8/8.1 machines with Microsoft Office 2010 and 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not safe. It just doesn't run macros and it doesn't even do a good job at that. I'm pretty sure it still downloads images. No one to my knowledge has done an in depth audit on Word's leaking when opening files, especially not protected view. http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2387069,00.asp